# Concatenating separate varchar values of date and time into full datetime in a single field

Tags: sql-server, datetime, concatenation, varchar

Maybe my question is too complex, or maybe I'm just not wording it properly, but I'm having a hard time finding an answer. I will be as brief and clear as I can be.

I have two separate tables in SQL Server 2005, each of which is updated through a separate application. Because of the limitations of those applications, the tables are built quite differently. In Table A, the date and time of the order is stored as a DATETIME in 108 format (i.e. 14/11/2013 08:15:00). In Table B, these values are split up automatically by the trigger which inserts them. They are divided into separate fields of the type VARCHAR (i.e. Day = '14/11/2013' and HourFrom = '0815').

These parameters are beyond my control, unfortunately. If I try to format either table differently from the SQL side, both applications will fail. (Don't get me started...)

My basic issue is this: When Table B is updated by the driver fulfilling the order, the new values need to be updated into Table A from Table B. If, for instance, the order was written in Table A from 08:15 to 09:00 but the driver actually picked it up at 08:30 and only completed the run at 09:15, the times in Table A must be updated according to those new values which the driver inserted into Table B.

My problem is that I am having a great deal of difficulty taking the VARCHAR values from Table B, inserting colons into the time so that a conversion function will accept them, concatenating them with the day field, and then updating the whole value into Table A. I get a lot of errors telling me all the different ways that my conversions fail, so I'm not going to list them all. If there is a quick, clean way to do this sort of conversion, I haven't found it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm new to SQL, which I think is why my cruel overlords threw this project on me; I'm learning a lot very quickly, but moments like these are very frustrating.

Why does something along these lines not seem to work for me?

```
@DAY = VARCHAR date value without time ("14/11/2013")
@HOURFROM = VARCHAR hour value ("0800")
```

[These values already established in the database on Table B]

```
convert(DATETIME,(@DAY+' '+LEFT(@HOURFROM,2)+':'+RIGHT(@HOURFROM,2)),108)
```

[I want to establish this value as DATETIME,108 and then update that value into Table A]

Answer (score 0):

or simply

```
select convert(datetime,@day+ ' '+stuff(@hourfrom,3,0,':'),103)
```

Comment: hmmm, in fact, the original code in the question works fine if he changes 108 to 103